# Error in connecting to Bloomberg API via Python on macOS

Tags: python, blpapi

Error in connecting to Bloomberg API via Python on macOS

I have installed the blpapi (3.16.2) and xbbg (0.7.6) in a new conda environment. Python version 3.8.10. I am running macOS Big Sur 11.4.

When trying to run the following code from the xbbg examples page, I get the below errors:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
```

```
09JUL2021_22:23:49.418 4564:123145553305600 WARN apicm_apiconnector.cpp:395 ApiConnector::socketConnectorCallback localhost: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8194, status=1, error 8 connect event failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:49.418 4564:123145553305600 WARN blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:151 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{1}.<localhost:8194> { platformId=0 } 127.0.0.1, session pool state=Failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:52.421 4564:123145553305600 WARN apicm_apiconnector.cpp:395 ApiConnector::socketConnectorCallback localhost: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8194, status=1, error 8 connect event failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:52.421 4564:123145553305600 WARN blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:151 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{1}.<localhost:8194> { platformId=0 } 127.0.0.1, session pool state=Failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:55.425 4564:123145553305600 WARN apicm_apiconnector.cpp:395 ApiConnector::socketConnectorCallback localhost: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8194, status=1, error 8 connect event failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:55.425 4564:123145553305600 WARN blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:151 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{1}.<localhost:8194> { platformId=0 } 127.0.0.1, session pool state=Failed 

09JUL2021_22:23:55.425 4564:123145553305600 WARN blpapi_platformcontroller.cpp:607 blpapi.session.platformcontroller.{1} Platform failed 3 consecutive connect attempts, stopped trying to reconnect. { PlatformId=0 }  

09JUL2021_22:23:55.425 4564:123145555439616 ERROR blpapi_sessionimpl.cpp:2424 blpapi.session.{1} Failed to start session: Failed to connect 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aveshenpillay/Desktop/@MSc_Data_Science/14_Python/04_Bloomberg/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bbg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xbbg/blp.py", line 47, in bdp
    request = process.create_request(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bbg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xbbg/core/process.py", line 46, in create_request
    srv = conn.bbg_service(service=service, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bbg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xbbg/core/conn.py", line 150, in bbg_service
    bbg_session(**kwargs).openService(service)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bbg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xbbg/core/conn.py", line 120, in bbg_session
    globals()[con_sym] = connect_bbg(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bbg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xbbg/core/conn.py", line 97, in connect_bbg
    else: raise ConnectionError('Cannot connect to Bloomberg')
ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Bloomberg

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I enter / input my login details for Bloomberg to be able to connect to the API. Is this even possible from a Mac set up or do I need to install Windows 10 using Boot Camp on a partition drive of my Mac and then install the Bloomberg terminal and Python to execute there?

Comment: To be able to connect to the Bloomberg desktop API, you need to log into the Bloomberg terminal  ***on the same machine*** (which requires a subscription).

Comment: I do have a subscription. The desktop API is not available for Mac, one needs to use Citrix receiver. Hence my question, if there is a work around? However, everything that I am reading suggests that you need to run a Windows session.

Comment: I don't think there is a way on a Mac, but then I've never really investigated.

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out @AveshenPillay? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: You need to use Windows to run the terminal software, can't be done on MacOS. Then, you can install the API and it will work so long as you are logged into the Terminal via fingerprint.